# Phone number custom field and woocommerce updating issue noticed

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I use Wordpress user frontend plugin to allow guests to post their woocommerce product on my website but I have observed some issues.

Firstly, I added a phone number field in the form, then also added advanced custom field plugin to my website, created a number field and set the field name to phone_field.

My plan was to capture the guests phone number into that number field created with ACF plugin. Note: I have already set it up properly as woocommerce product type so it displays in woocommerce product alongside other fields like virtual, regular price, sale price..

Now whenever guests submit their woocommerce product I notice their phone number dont reveal in the acf phone number field on woocommerce edit page, but the number can be seen when inspected. So I dont know whats wrong.

Secondly when I decide to update the field to change the number of the guest it doesnt change, it still returns same old number.

Now I have on my own as admin created a post from the woocommerce admin area and added a number and it showed and also changed to a new number and updated it still changed.,

So this issue is primarily faced only on guests submitted posts. Please look into it and give me a solution to fix this.

see images..
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]